# nested quotes in plpgsql EXECUTE statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, literals

I am writing `plpgsql` function with table name as parameter to handle my postgis database update tasks, but encounters problem about quotes in quotes in `EXECUTE` statement.

here is the plain SQL script and it works fine:

```
UPDATE baoluo SET sfzgjsyd='同时落在总规建设用地内外' 
        FROM lu_plan AS lu
        WHERE ST_Overlaps(lu.geom, baoluo.geom) 
        AND lu.is_construc = '建设用地'
```

when in plpgsql, I used double quotes for Chinese characters,here is the related part of code:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION process(_tb1 regclass, town_name TEXT, town_id TEXT) 
RETURNS VOID AS
$func$
DECLARE
   city_name text := '文昌市';  -- assign at declaration
   city_code text := '469005';
BEGIN
    --更新字段：
    EXECUTE format('
        UPDATE %s SET sfzgjsyd="同时落在总规建设用地内外" 
        FROM lu_plan 
        WHERE ST_Overlaps(lu_plan.geom, %s.geom) 
        AND lu_plan.is_construc = "建设用地"', _tb1, _tb1); 
END; 
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
select process('public.baoluo', '保罗镇', '469005000');
```

I expect it work fine but the log shows error with `the field not exists`.

Comment: Standard SQL (and PostgreSQL) uses single quotes for string literals (such as `文昌市'`) and double quotes for identifiers (such as table and column names). So `"同时落在总规建设用地内外"` and `"建设用地"` are interpreted as column names, you need to use single quotes for those or let `format` handle the quoting and supply them as arguments.

Comment: @muistooshort However, In `format()` strings,  single quotes will get wrong with  Chinese characters; And I don't want to use  arguments because I need many arguments like this in my whole plpgsql function, any other suggestions?  by Deyu Tian

Comment: `format('%L', '建设用地')` works as expected and produces `'建设用地'`. Also, you should be using `%I` not `%s` for the table names. If using `%L` is a problem for some reason then you can double the single quotes to escape them like in any other string literal (i.e. `sfzgjsyd=''同时落在总规建设用地内外''`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In format() strings, single quotes will get wrong with Chinese characters.

There is a problem with nested quotes, not with Chinese characters. Use dollar-quoting and `%I` for identifiers:

```
...
EXECUTE format($ex$
    UPDATE %I SET sfzgjsyd= '同时落在总规建设用地内外'
    FROM lu_plan 
    WHERE ST_Overlaps(lu_plan.geom, %I.geom) 
    AND lu_plan.is_construc = '建设用地'
    $ex$, _tb1, _tb1); 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried with @muistooshort suggestion of double the single quotes, it works fine.

```
...
EXECUTE format('
    UPDATE %I SET sfzgjsyd=''同时落在总规建设用地内外'' 
    FROM lu_plan 
    WHERE ST_Overlaps(lu_plan.geom, %I.geom) 
    AND lu_plan.is_construc = ''建设用地''', _tb1, _tb1); 
...
```